# JSTL 1.2 doesn't work well on Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jstl, weblogic-10.x

The JSTL 1.2 core tag doesn't work well on my Weblogic 10.3.5, but using JSTL 1.0 is fine. Following is the behaviour:

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<c:out value="${1+2}"/>
```

Output: 3

If I changed the URI to `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`, the output will be "${1+2}" and it is like printing the expression directly as a string. I don't get any error/exception in both case. Following is my setting:

web.xml:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

and a jar file "glassfish.jstl_1.2.0.1.jar" is placed under /WEB-INF/lib/.

Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this on the top of your jsp page.

`<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

Comment: OMG, it works! I got stuck in this problem for few days. BTW, isn't isELIgnored false by default? It seems to be true for this parameter. Thanks a lot, Quincy

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure but the default=false may not be on selvet 2.5. You may be able to test it by changing the dtd to 2.4.